# fstream can't read pagemap?

Tags: c++, linux, fstream

I'm trying to decode the /proc/[pid]/pagemap file for a process but the following code using fstream outputs value of buffer as 0:

```
int main() {

  const uint64_t addr       = 0x1396010;
  const uint8_t  offsetBits = 12; 
  const uint8_t  entryBytes = 8;

  unsigned long long offset = (addr >> offsetBits) * entryBytes;
  unsigned long long buffer = 0;

  std::ifstream file ("/proc/19710/pagemap", std::ifstream::binary);

 if (file) {
   std::cout << "Got the file" << std::endl;
 }

 file.seekg(offset, file.beg);
 file.read((char*)(&buffer), 8); 

 std::cout << "Offset:: " << offset << std::endl; 

 std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

while the same program using C file functions, outputs correct value of val:

```
int main() {

    const uint64_t addr       = 0x1396010;
    const uint8_t  offsetBits = 12;
    const uint8_t  entryBytes = 8;

    uint64_t offset = (addr >> offsetBits) * entryBytes;

    std::cout << "Offset: " << offset << std::endl;

    char pagemap[256];

    sprintf(pagemap, "%s", "/proc/19710/pagemap");

    FILE* file = fopen(pagemap, "rb");

    fseek(file, offset, SEEK_SET);

    uint64_t val = 0;

    fread(&val, entryBytes, 1, file);

    std::cout << val << std::endl;
}
```

Both programs were ran with sudo command. I can't figure out why the first program is not working with pagemap file but works correctly with any other binary file.

Comment: Have a look at the `strace` output for each to see what they're doing differently.

Comment: I ran both programs with `strace`. Although both program use same sys calls despite different functions, the first one was unable to read from file descriptor with this error. `read(3, 0x8d5c20, 8191) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)`. After some hit and trail I discovered the count value (third arg) supplied by fstream is causing the read command to fail. **I've no idea why.** I executed the program using only sys calls and it doesn't accepted the 8191 value. Functions used in program 2 supplies 1024 as count value which is working correctly. So, I guess its fstream API's fault?

Comment: So it's using a larger input buffer and causing a read of unavailable data, and that's why procfs returns failure?

Comment: Possibly. According to read man page: `read attempts to read up to count bytes from file descriptor fd into the buffer starting at buf.` I tried different values for count some caused segfault, some,  like 8191, were rejected for this file as invalid argument. I don't know what factors affected the ifstream read method to chose this count value.

Comment: It's the buffer size.

Comment: `unsigned long long buffer = 0; ... file.read((char*)(&buffer), 8);` what is the purpose of this nonsense?

Comment: `file.read` accepts only `char *` pointer so cast is necessary. Second argument specifies the number of bytes to be read.